# Logging not working in ContextListener at application shutdown

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, log4j2, servletcontextlistener

I have a Java Web Application with a single ServletContextListener that creates and uses a log4j Logger both in application startup and shutdown.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    getLogger().info("My context is initialized");
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    getLogger().info("My context is destroyed");
  }

  private Logger getLogger() {
     return LogManager.getLogger();
  }
}
```

Log4j configuration file is defined in web.xml, also I'm using log4j-web jar provided in the log4j release.

During startup the log message is printed properly, however in shutdown my configuration file cannot be found so the logger cannot be configured and shows this error message:

```
2018-12-11 16:56:44,722 localhost-startStop-2 ERROR No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
```

I created a sample project to reproduce this issue:

https://github.com/katanagari7c1/tomcat-shutdown-test

It can be reproduced simply by starting/stopping a Tomcat with this application.

Any clue of how to fix this? Am I missing something?